# Prisma database with Axios: How can I fix the relationship error when creating a new post?

Tags: database, axios, relationship, prisma

Prima two references to the same table.
I have a `Post` model and a `User` model. I want each `Post` to have one `author` (`User` type) and one `recipient` (`User` type). I want each `User` to have an `outbox`, which consists of posts they made (`post[]` type), and an `inbox`, which consists of posts they received (`post[]` type).

Basically,

- 1-m between post & author
- 1-m between post & recipient

Prisma (simplified version)

```
model Post {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  title     String
  authorId  String    
  recepientEmail String 
  author    User     @relation(name: "author", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  recepient User     @relation(name: "recepient", fields: [recepientEmail], references: [email])
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  email         String?   @unique
  outbox        Post[]    @relation(name: "author")
  inbox         Post[]    @relation(name: "recipient")
}
```

There are no errors in my prisma file, but for some reason, I can't create a new post to my database. It just errors out.

```
const post = await prisma.post.create({
                data: {
                    title: title,
                    authorId: prismaUser.id,
                    recepientEmail: recepient,
                }
            })
```

When I comment out the `recipient` field in `Post` and `inbox` field in `User`, this code works. I have checked that all the fields I'm passing in are correct and as expected.

What should I do?